# Shall it be possible to comment on answers to questions I have bounty for even if I don't have 50 reputation?

Tags: feature-request, comments, bounties, privileges

I understand that this is a rather corner case situation, but I managed to end up in it, and it is very frustrating.

1. I found a question I need an answer for in a community I am not part of. The question is not answered.
2. I joined the community and got 100 bonus reputation, since I was a member of other communities
3. I offered a bounty to that question, spending all the reputation I have.
4. People provide answers.

Now, offering a bounty, I would like to be able to discuss those answers (in particular, to point out that they do not work), but I can't do it, since I just spent all my reputation.

Would it be reasonable to allow people who started a bounty to comment on the answers?

Comment: Simply start a 50 points bounty, not 100. Problem  solved.